# Google API doesnt work when published (React-Native app) but fine on emulator (Expo)

Tags: react-native, google-api, expo, android-manifest, react-native-maps

React native app works fine on Android Studio emulator (using Expo), but when I publish to Play Store and open from there, I cant get past Splash screen (it just closes).

When I ask for feedback, the stack trace says:
RuntimeException API key not found. Check that meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="your API key" is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

1. If the API key isnt right, then why does it run fine on the emulator?
2. What AndroidManifest.xml should I edit? I have 20 files with that name:
   "...\node_modules\react-native-maps\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml"
   "...\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\androidTest\AndroidManifest.xml" etc

Answer (score 1):

try to **add the Api Key on the app.json** file:

**For IOS:**
Copy your API key into app.json under the ios.config.googleMapsApiKey field.

**For Android:**
Copy your API Key into your app.json under the android.config.googleMaps.apiKey field.

Like this:

```
 "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
      "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  }
```

for more information you read this:

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#deploy-app-with-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

If you have used release keystore sha while getting API key then you may face this issue. Play store re-signs the application with its own keys while uploading app to store. In this case you will need to get the sha from play connect and use this sha for API key.